# Get a control by reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to get a control [textbox,label,button ...etc] from my page by it's ID using reflection

In my case I have a class that all other system pages inherit from it and this class is override the onload event to change some properties to some controls

like set the visibility state for textbox by it's name but as I don't have the control direct on the page as I may have it on content place holder in master page so I couldn't use findcontrol method also I think recursive function to find the control will take too much time

So **I try to do it with refelection to find a control with its name** then change the visable or enable state for it

I used the FieldInfo class but doesn't work with me

```
FieldInfo fi = this.GetType().GetField("ControlID", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
```

Any help !

Comment: Tanks for you all about your useful solution... But the problem is to get the control with refelection not recursively

Comment: all answers useless, none of them uses reflection..

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
  Control myControl = this.FindControl("TextBox2");
  if(myControl !=null)
  {
       // Do Stuff
  }
```

Comment: thank you for try , but I don't have known count of levels so I couldn't use findcontrols directlly

Comment: @AshOoO: "count of levels"? What do you mean?

Comment: Mean that I may have master page with content place holder so just use this.findcontrol won't work aslo in other page I have controls direct on the page other controls maybe in content with sub content >>> So use this.findcontrol doesn't work for all directlly

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to *recursively* look for your control with FindControl, and then calling itself?

```
private static Control FindNestedControl(string id, Control parent)
{
    Control item = parent.FindControl(id);

    if(item == null) 
    {
        foreach(var child in parent.Controls)
        {
            item = child.FindNestedControl(id, child);

            if(item != null)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And call it passing the current instance of the page through:

```
Control item = FindNestedControl("bob", this);
```

This can be slow however - so do look out for that if there's a whole bunch of controls on the page :)

Another way to do it would be simply expose the controls as properties in your base class:

```
public abstract class BasePage : Page
{
    #region Properties

    /// Gets the textbox for editing in derived classes.
    protected TextBox SomeTextBox
    {
       return this.textBox; }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And the final way to do it would be to hook into derived classes in your base class:

```
public abstract class BasePage : Page
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when loading the page.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The event arguments.</param>
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            // Do some basic setup.

            // Now pass the controls to the derived classes.
            this.ConfigureControl(this.mainText);
            this.ConfigureControl(this.nameDropDown);
            this.ConfigureControl(this.someOtherControl);            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides hook for derived classes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control">The core control.</param>
        protected virtual void ConfigureControl(Control control)
        {
        }
 }
```

And then override in your derived page:

```
protected override void ConfigureControl(Control control)
{
    switch(control.ID) 
    {
        case "mainText":
        TextBox mainText = (TextBox)control;
        mainText.Text = "works";
        break;
    }
}
```

Out of these i would probably use the second if there's not so many controls. The first method is useful when dealing with repeaters and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's very useful extension method to get child controls recursively:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetChildControls(this Control control)
{
    var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<Control>() : Enumerable.Empty<Control>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Control> allChildren = parent.GetChildControls();
```